# Angular does not show changes on manual browser reload or file saves

Tags: angular, macos, angular-cli

Having trouble with Angular - it will not show changes, either on a file save or browser manual refresh. I've seen several threads about this issue but none of them have worked for me. In order to see a change, I have to cancel the ng serve process and restart it.

I've tried these:

- sudo ng serve -o --watch
- npm install --save @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4
- echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
- uninstall Angular, clean cache, reinstall Angular
- added "@angular/webpack": "^1.2.4", to the devDependencies in package.json
- set Chrome to disable cache

None of these work. I'm at a complete loss. Is there anything else I can try to get this functioning properly?

If I've left out any pertinent info, I apologize - I am a newbie, obviously. Please ask for any info I can provide, and any help would be appreciated..

I'm on a Mac using OS 10.10.5

Comment: Can you provide a capture of the terminal when you run ng serve? Curious if it's displaying any warnings.

Comment: I don't know how to add images here but there doesn't seem to be any errors. This is the output:

Comment: ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
                                                T Date: 2018-07-13T19:14:31.409Z          
Hash: c04edd270bb838a71b5e
Time: 19185ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 10.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]

Comment: chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.06 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.

Comment: What editor are you using? and what version of `angular-cli`

Comment: Using Sublime Text. I don't know the version of angular-cli but I installed it today following the instructions on the angular.io site so I assume it's the latest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `ng serve --poll=1000` .

If that does not work you should also look into folder paths having name spaces and remove the spaces i.e 'Some Folder' to SomeFolder.

Comment: my folder name already had no spaces. I tried that command it is working. Can you please elaborate on what that's doing? and thank you!

Comment: This sorted my one project where I had to hard fresh every time I made an update anywhere. This has helped me out thanks!